# Namenode and Datanode not starting in hadoop

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, makefile

I am new to hadoop map reduce. I am getting the following error while starting dfs.

```
satya@satyaPC:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode$ start-all.sh

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
15/10/02 20:38:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

As a result of this warning, name node and data node are not getting started. This is the result of jps command.

```
satya@satyaPC:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode$ jps

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 

6113 Jps

5755 ResourceManager

6077 NodeManager

5592 SecondaryNameNode
```

I tried to fix it using the following link: http://www.csrdu.org/nauman/2014/01/23/geting-started-with-hadoop-2-2-0-building/
But this resulted in the following error.

```
satya@satyaPC:/usr/local/hadoop/protobuf-2.5.0$ make install

Making install in .

make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/hadoop/protobuf-2.5.0'

make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/local/hadoop/protobuf-2.5.0'

make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.

test -z "/usr/lib/pkgconfig" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 protobuf.pc protobuf-lite.pc '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'

/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/lib/pkgconfig/protobuf.pc’: Permission denied

/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/lib/pkgconfig/protobuf-lite.pc’: Permission denied

Makefile:543: recipe for target 'install-pkgconfigDATA' failed

make[2]: *** [install-pkgconfigDATA] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/hadoop/protobuf-2.5.0'

Makefile:901: recipe for target 'install-am' failed

make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/hadoop/protobuf-2.5.0'

Makefile:568: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed

make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any help in fixing the bug is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.